# numpy - explanation of numpy.prod

Tags: numpy, cartesian-product

## Question

Please suggest approaches how I can understand why product of empty list/array is 1 and the behavior of numpy.prod. Any good reading, articles as so far I could not find any (as in the bottom).

- [numpy.prod](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html)

> The product of an empty array is the neutral element 1
>
> ````
> np.prod([])
> 1.0 ```
> ````

And why the product of empty array `a = np.empty((1,5), dtype=float)` is `0` not `1`? If the definition `product of empty list/array is 1` is true, then I suppose it should be 1.

```
a = np.empty((1,5), dtype=float)
a.prod()
---
0
```

## Background

Having a confusion why product (multiplication of elements in array) is `1`, not `0`. Researched into articles but could not find a clear explanation.

- [Wikipedia Empty product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product)

```
math.prod([2, 3, 5]) # = 30
math.prod([2, 3])    # = 6
math.prod([2])       # = 2
math.prod([])        # = 1
```

```
(* 2 2 2)   ; evaluates to 8
(* 2 2)     ; evaluates to 4
(* 2)       ; evaluates to 2
(*)         ; evaluates to 1
```

It seems related with category theory but the explanation is cryptic and could not understand what it tried to explain.

- [Why is an Empty Sum 0 and an Empty Product 1?](https://dzone.com/articles/why-empty-sum-0-and-empty)

> You can find the full definition of a categorical product here. Below
> I give the definition leaving out details that go away when we look at
> empty products.
>
> The product of a set of objects is an object P such that given any
> other object X … there exists a unique morphism from X to P such that
> ….
>
> If you’ve never seen this before, you might rightfully wonder what in
> the world this has to do with products. You’ll have to trust me on
> this one.
>
> When the set of objects is empty, the missing parts of the definition
> above don’t matter, so we’re left with requiring that there is a
> unique morphism  from each object X to the product P. In other
> words, P is a terminal object, often denoted 1. So in category theory,
> you can say empty products are 1.

Comment: The reason is, that `np.empty` is not an empty array, but an array with uninitialized values according to https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html. You can check with e.g. `print(np.empty(1,5), dtype=float)`

Comment: Why an empty product yields 1, is a question better asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

The code for `np.prod` is:

```
return _wrapreduction(a, np.multiply, 'prod', axis, dtype, out,
                      keepdims=keepdims, initial=initial, where=where)
```

in other words it just does:

```
In [176]: np.multiply.reduce(np.arange(1,6))
Out[176]: 120
```

That action might be clearer if we use `accumulate` instead:

```
In [177]: np.multiply.accumulate(np.arange(1,6))
Out[177]: array([  1,   2,   6,  24, 120])
```

Basically `np.prod` is the multiply equivalent of `np.sum`.

If you look at the docs of `np.multiply.reduce` you get a description of the general `ufunc.reduce` method. It talks about an `initial` value, which may be a default, or may be user specificd.  All `reduce` operations have to start with something, preferable something that makes sense in the context.  And that initial value will apply when the argument is empty - 0 values.

```
In [181]: np.multiply.reduce(np.arange(1,6),initial=10)
Out[181]: 1200
In [182]: np.multiply.reduce(np.arange(1,6),initial=0)
Out[182]: 0
```

Note that I had to start the `arange` at 1.  If there's any 0 in the argument, the `prod` will be 0!.

```
In [184]: np.multiply.reduce([],initial=0)
Out[184]: 0.0
In [185]: np.multiply.reduce([],initial=1)
Out[185]: 1.0
In [186]: np.multiply.reduce([],initial=10)
Out[186]: 10.0
```

As for your confusion with the `np.empty` function, did you even bother to look at `a`?

```
In [187]: np.empty((1,5), float)
Out[187]: array([[4.9e-324, 9.9e-324, 1.5e-323, 2.0e-323, 2.5e-323]])
In [188]: np.array([])
Out[188]: array([], dtype=float64)
```

`np.empty` does not produce the same thing as `np.array([])`.  Note the difference in shape ((1,5) vs (0,), as well as value(s).